# Some images downloaded corrupted via using CURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm using CURL in PHP to download images from URLs from CSV file but if there are more than one images in a single line than some of the images downloaded corrupted and the size of that image is 0 byte.
Example:- 
If the CSV file is like this then the second file always corrupted.

```
Image 1, "https://d2qx4k6xgs9iri.cloudfront.net/ProductImages/ce363947-f23a-46d6-b106-1201cdca37f0.jpg, https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png"
```

But If I removed first or second image than the image successfully saved. Example:

```
Image 2, https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png
```

Here is my code that reads a CSV File

```
    $file = fopen($file, "r");
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $data = fgetcsv($file);
        $images = $data[1];
        $images = explode(',', $images); //exploding images by ,
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $milliseconds = md5(round(microtime(true) * 1000)) . '.jpg';
            $imagename = saveImage($image, $milliseconds);
        }
}
```

Below `saveImage` function

```
function saveImage($url,$image_name){

echo $url.'<br/>'; //URL is correct and have image. I have checked it manually
$ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    $fp = fopen('assets/products/large/' . $image_name,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

The Exact Sample for CSV File which I'm Using

```
Images 1, "https://d2qx4k6xgs9iri.cloudfront.net/ProductImages/ce363947-f23a-46d6-b106-1201cdca37f0.jpg, https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png"
Images 2, https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png
Images 3, "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png, https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/girl.png"
Images 4, "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/goldhill.bmp, https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/tulips.png"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue may well be that there is space in the url before the protocol - using `trim` to remove the space would help. Rather than use curl for testing I simply used `file_get_contents` and it downloaded all the files OK.

```
$dir = 'c:/temp/downloads/';

$file=__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img.csv';
$file=fopen( $file, 'r' );


while( !feof( $file ) ){
    $line = fgetcsv( $file );
    if( !empty( $line[1] ) ){
        $urls = explode( ',', $line[1] );

        foreach( $urls as $url ){
            $url=trim( $url );

            $bytes = file_put_contents( $dir . basename( $url ), file_get_contents( $url ) );
            printf('Saved %s - size: %sKb<br />',basename( $url ),$bytes / 1024 );
        }
    }
}
fclose( $file );
```

The curl function also needed a little tweak - as the urls are over SSL then you really should add additional parameters to the curl request. I modified the function like so:

```
function saveImage( $url, $image_path ){
    global $cacert;
    $fp = fopen( $image_path, 'w+' );

    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp );

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Where `$cacert` is defined elsewhere but essentially, on my system is `c:\wwwroot\cacert.pem` ~ you can download a copy from [here - curl.haxx.se](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)

I ran this code rather than the above like so:

```
while( !feof( $file ) ){
    $line = fgetcsv( $file );
    if( !empty( $line[1] ) ){
        $urls = explode( ',', $line[1] );

        foreach( $urls as $url ){
            $url=trim( $url );
            saveImage( $url, $dir . basename( $url ) );
        }
    }
}
fclose( $file );
```

[image: screenshot showing downloaded images]